# How to request multiple request with Rx-Java and Retrofit at same time?

Tags: android, request, rx-java, retrofit2

I want to get more than 3 response from server using retrofit at the same time. but just 2 requests will have a response.

I'm using Retrofit and Rxjava.

Also I used .clone() method to duplicate request.

Click (https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-reuse-and-analyze-requests-2)!

This is ResponseActivity :

```java
public class ResponseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ResponseViewModel mViewModel;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    protected CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.response_main);
        mViewModel = new ResponseViewModel();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb_response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
  mViewModel.getText()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new MySingleObserver<Text>(compositeDisposable) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Text value) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: " + value.getText());
                    }
                });
        mViewModel.getText()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new MySingleObserver<Text>(compositeDisposable) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Text value) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: " + value.getText());
                    }
                });

        mViewModel.getText()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new MySingleObserver<Text>(compositeDisposable) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Text value) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: " + value.getText());
                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        compositeDisposable.clear();
    }
}
```

And this is My ViewModel

```java
public class ResponseViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public Single<Text> getText() {
        Single<Text> call= apiService.getText();
        return call;
        }
}
```

I just got 2 of 3 response. sometimes I got more than 2.
I don't know Why that happens.

Comment: why are you doing same call 3 times ?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the error handler? Maybe there's an exception.

Comment: How do you know that you get only two results? Maybe logcat is collapsing identical lines

Comment: @akshay_shahane this is HomeWork from My Teacher. And I must do multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos : when I'm using Debug tools there is no problem because the requests are not at the same time and there is time to get all request.

Comment: @gpunto no I check logcat carefully. just 2 items received.

Comment: What is the implementation of `MySingleObserver`?